# Passing variable from Laravel to Javascript and return on click

Tags: javascript, laravel, parameter-passing

I have the next button

```
<button type="button" onclick="return myButton({{$cars->id_cars}}, {{$price}});"</button>
```

I think something here is wrong because I introduced a value, and the value what I get is with "-". For example I have price=520, what I get is -520.

Edit with function:

```
function myButton(id_car, price) {
    $("#id_car").val(id_car);
    $("#price").val(price);
    }
```

Comment: did you printing out its value into your view and whats exactly did you get

Comment: could you post myButton function?

Comment: Yeah i'm printing the value. If value is 250, what I get is -250.

Comment: how about when you console.log(price); still (-) ?

Comment: yep.. I want to know if it's ok how the text is written.